# How to Classify the imbalanced Dataset using SVM

Tags: python, svm, imbalanced-data

I am using the SVM, and My dataset is imbalanced. I got the result in which it classified Class 0 as 99% and Class 1 as 1%. Is there any way to correctly classify the imbalances dataset using SVM.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways you can work with imbalanced dataset. I have most commonly used a couple of these:

1. Penalize for wrong output: If class `A` has much less samples than class `B`, then you can increase the penalty incurred for incorrect classification of class `A`.
2. Use the [SMOTE](https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/) module. It basically takes the convex combination of two points in a given class and assigns it the same label as the two chosen points.

Other possible options can include looking at different evaluation metrics and validation strategies like [Stratified K Fold](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cross-validation-for-imbalanced-classification/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to adapt an unbalanced dataset to use it for regression/classification. Here I'm going to describe the oversampling and undersampling methods.

In **oversampling**, you duplicate the data for the minority class, even when you have rows in your data that are exactly the same. In **undersampling** you pick all the data that has class 1 and pick the same number of samples that have label 0 (this is only a good option if you have a high number of samples).

You could also use a mix of the two. Something like:

```
def obtain_equal_idx(idx_0, idx_1, n_samples, ratio_unbalance):
    idx_1_repeated = np.repeat(idx_1, (n_samples // len(idx_1)) + 1)

    idx_0s = np.random.choice(idx_0, ratio_unbalance * (n_samples // 2), replace=False)
    idx_delay = np.random.choice(idx_1_repeated, n_samples // 2, replace=False)
    return np.concatenate([idx_0s, idx_delay])
```

With `idx_0` being the indexes of your whole dataset labeled as 0, `idx_1` being the same for the data labeled as 1, `n_samples` is the number of samples you want to get, and `ratio_unbalance` is a number (usually 2 or 3) that allow the data you get to be a bit unbalanced so that your model knows that the data is not completely balanced.